# What does "characterize game-theoretically" mean, formally?

Tags: general-topology, definition, game-theory

In a topology paper a few years ago, there was an open problem listed which asked if a certain property $P$ of all topological spaces, in this case the property of being semi-Rothberger, can be characterized game-theoretically. Now, if someone comes up with a game-theoretical characterization, then we know the answer is yes. However, to prove the answer is no, we have to define what a game-theoretical characterization of some property is. Has anyone defined it rigorously? Or, is this yet another of those things in math papers where there is no formal definition of it?

Comment: It is another of those things in math papers where there is no formal definition.